# How to pass formdata and files in angular 2 to back end?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
save(model: Customer) {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;

    for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
    }
    const formModel= this.myForm.value;
    this.reg.appform(this.application,formData,formModel).subscribe(()=> this.goBack());
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

this is `ts` file where both `FormData` and `FormValue` is passing to service
then:

```
appform(url,FormData,info){
   console.log(FormData);
   // window.alert("url");
   return this._http.post(url,FormData,JSON.stringify({ info}))
                    .map(()=>"");
}
```

this is `Form.service.ts` to throw data to back end

```
$post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_date);
// print_r($data);
// exit;

$MemberData = array(
    "OrgName"=>$data->info->name,
    "MemberName"=>$data->info->MemberName)
```

this is how i'm receiving data from backend (Controller in codeigniter). 
in that `service.ts` file, if model is passed in the second position data is sent perfectly but file is not uploaded. If `FormData` passed in the second position File is being uploaded but data shows error like,

> trying to read non-object value

Comment: why do you stringify the body? does the server expect text not a json object?

Comment: Server expect the json object to process. If another option please suggest me. Thank you

Comment: if the server expects a json object, you need to send json, not a json string. `return this._http.post(url,FormData,info))` then `.map(res => res.json())` if you expect json unless youre using angular 5 in which case the map isnt required

Comment: ** Trying to get property of non-object**  this is the error i'm getting from backend when i post the data.

Comment: as a string or as json?

Comment: as json. i've changed the code in service.ts as you said and tried. Its showing the same error.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. I receive the formValue in the backend like, $data=array();
$name=json_decode($_POST['name']);

Comment: but you still need to remove the stringify, you should never stringify the body